# Android AsyncTask wait until finished

Tags: java, android, web-services

I am calling a web service using `AsyncTask` in a android app and I can not figure out how to wait until the `onPostExecute` has finished:

```
//Call Async Web Service here 
AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
task.execute();
//Need to wait to fill this in ** Its not  waiting.
String sCall = rslt;
String[] aCall = sCall.split("//|");

private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
        GetURL();
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
        try{
            //Results HERE
            rslt = resultString.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {rslt = ex.toString()+ "|" + ex.toString();}

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the getStatus() method.

```
while (task.getStatus() != Status.FINISHED);
```

A better way to do this would be to call `split()` inside the `onPostExecute()` method, since `onPostExecute()` runs on the UI thread anyway and the `while()` call would block the current thread it's running in.

Comment: This is the correct solution but to put the split in the onPostExecute()

Comment: I would not recommend that while loop.  You're telling the system to do nothing as fast as possible until the task status changes - not a good idea especially on the UI thread.  Nick Cardoso's suggestion of a callback is much better if you need to do something after the task finishes.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not clear on what you can't/don't want to do from onPostExecute but you can use a callback if you are wanting to execute something that's not coupled to the task (so that you can run the task from anywhere)

```
private class OnFinishedListener {
    void onFinished(String rslt);
}

private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private OnFinishedListener mAfter;

    public AsyncCallWS(OnFinishedListener after) {
        mAfter = after;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        ....
        if (mAfter != null) {
            //you didnt illustrate what resultString is, you might
            //want this to be the returned value from doInBackground
            mAfter.onFinished(resultString.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Usage

```
new AsyncCallWS(new OnFinishedListener {
    public void onFinished(String rslt) {
        //for example
        String sCall = rslt;
        String[] aCall = sCall.split("//|");
    }
}).execute();
```

Comment: Using callback is good idea. Also, you could use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) for notification with results instead of callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Tasks.await(task)` in a background thread. Do not use this in UI thread. You can also set timeout for your task `Tasks.await(task, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);`